# Boolean Logic Simplification: AB+A'B'=?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have some problem simplifying the equation AB+A'B'=  ?  Is there any straight forward answer like AB'+A'B = A^B  ; (^)=XOR sign ?

Comment: This is not a programming question, rather it is a Math question. Please ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ with the logic tag.

Comment: yeah, seems you're right . I'm a CSE student and I've found this problem on my CSE231 course named Digital Logic. I'm was eager to find the solution so I din't give it much thought. I will be careful next time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the XNOR function, which typically doesn't occur often enough to warrant its own operator. It's the negation of `XOR`, though, which can be seen by applying De Morgan's law twice.

```
AB + A'B' = ((AB)'(A'B')')'
          = ((A' + B')(A + B))'
          = (A'A + B'A + A'B + B'B)'
          = (0 + AB' + A'B + 0)'
          = (AB' + A'B)'
          = (A ^ B)'
```

or by simply comparing truth tables

```
A  B    A ^ B   AB + A'B'
-------------------------
0  0      0        1
0  1      1        0
1  0      1        0
1  1      0        1
```

(Put another way, XNOR is equivalence for two arguments, so you can think of `A XNOR B` as an operator that converts comparison to a value. `A XNOR B` equals 1 if `A == B` is true, 0 if it is false.)

Comment: I think there is a minor mistake in this answer. AA'=0 and not 1.

Comment: Indeed; not sure what I was thinking, but the following step was done correctly, as if I had typed 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Yes yes, the following steps were all correctly done..